# Formal representation of cases in mathematics

Tags: logic, notation

Trivial part:

Solving a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, where $a,b,c$ are real numbers, requires to consider two cases: (i) $a=0$ and (ii) $a \neq 0$. In the first case there is only one solution: $x=-c/b$, while in the second one there are two (complex) solutions: $x=(-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a$.

My problem (I believe that it is tricky, otherwise I would not ask you for help):

I am looking for the most formal representation of the facts stated above expressed in formalism of logic or set theory or any other, without any comments that are essential for understanding it (such solution can be found on Wikipedia's site). The part that is bothering me the most is: how to deal with cases in formal logic/mathematics, without any comments and explanations? There are some formal and explicit ways to do it in many programming languages (e.g. "select case" construct in Fortran), however I do not see the right way to do it using formal mathematical notation.

Comment: A quadratic equation cannot have $a=0$...(by definition)...

Comment: True, let's then think of it as a general equation.

Comment: The "general method" is [Poof by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion).

Comment: The method is formalized by [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) rule.

Comment: It seems to be somewhat pointless to ask for a formal way to represent proofs-by-cases without telling us **which proof formalism you want the answer to work with**. There are several quite different concepts of formal proof available (which all work for formalizing mathematics in general, and provably prove the same things, but differ in how they do this) -- and they generally handle proofs-by-cases in different ways to. It won't help you much to know how a proof by cases is represented in classical sequent calculus, for example, if what you know already is Hilbert-like systems.

Comment: I have formalized proof by cases in my proof-checking software (DC Proof 2.0) as follows: In your case, you would first invoke the equivalent of the law of the excluded middle to obtain: $a=0\lor a\neq 0$. Then prove in turn that $a=0\implies P$ and $a\neq 0 \implies P$. Combining these three results, you can infer using the Cases Rule that $P$ is true, where $P$ is the proposition you want to prove.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Nevertheless, I did not want to have a proof, I wanted to have a "formal representation" of the facts stated in "the trivial part" of my question. Do you think this is the same?

Answer (score 0):

$$(\forall a\in\Bbb{R}-\{0\})(\forall b,c,x\in\Bbb{R})($$
$$(ax^2+bx+c=0\ \Rightarrow\ (x=(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a\ \vee\ x=(-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a)))$$
$$\wedge\ (\forall b\in\Bbb{R}-\{0\})(\forall c,x\in\Bbb{R})(bx+c=0\ \Rightarrow\ x=-\tfrac{c}{b})$$

There are many other ways to put it, and you could also take $x\in\Bbb{C}$ in stead of $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: This is wrong because you cannot have division by $a$ when it could be zero. Now you're going to argue that you're not supposed to evaluate the consequent of the implication when the condition is false, but that is not the mathematical definition of implication, so no go. Same for $b$.

Comment: I'm no logician, as you can tell. I was just trying to make a point. Anyway is it better now?

Comment: It's the first reasonable step in attempting to get rid of the problem. However, depending on your logic system, the restricted quantifier may face the same problem, because typically logicians say that "$\forall x \in S\ ( ... )$" is simply short-form for $\forall x\ ( x \in S \rightarrow ... )$. You would be fine if your logic system **natively** allows restricted quantification (which I would also agree is a good thing).

Comment: The best way in my opinion is to allow guarded conditionals (just like in programming language), but somehow mathematicians never bothered to invent notation for them even though they mentally guard consequents.

Comment: Servaes, thank you for the answer. I was almost sure that sooner or later something like this will pop out. I do not know what are your feelings, but I find it ugly and highly unpractical. How are yours?

Comment: user21820, thank you for your comments. Could you elaborate on the "guarded conditionals"? Do you have any knowledge about projects, attempts to make mathematical notation resemble programming language (as we both pointed out, such problems are easily resolved in programming)?

Comment: @user21820 Most logical systems don’t even allow partial functions. So you would define division even when the denominator is zero (just setting it to some arbitrary value). Whenever you use division, you add the condition that the denominator be non-zero (like in this answer). Then it is irrelevant that the results are non-sensical in case the denominator is zero because the implication is true in that case anyways.

Comment: @Cat: I have my own ideas, but have never seen it used in conventional mathematics. For example, We can write "$A {?\land} B$" to mean "$A$ and then $B$" (don't check $B$ if $A$ is already false), which allows $B$ to syntactically depend on the truth of $A$. Similarly for $A {?\rightarrow} B$ for the guarded conditional. This is how people think in practice so I don't see why not. It seems however that people who devise logic don't really care whether it is practical...

Comment: @EikeSchulte: I know that that's the standard way of dealing with it. But that's clearly not the way people do things in practice. Don't think that it just has to do with partial functions. In ZFC you have no such thing as the function application syntax "$f(x)$". Why then do we write it? Furthermore we only write it in the context where we have proved that $f$ is a function whose domain includes $x$, and this syntax is meaningless if $f$ is not a function. I of course know how to get around this, but most people don't even bother to think about it.

Comment: @Cat "I was almost sure that sooner or later something like this will pop out ... I find it ugly and highly unpractical." Well, that's the tradeoff: more "purely formal" representations are harder to actually use (think machine code versus, say, Python).